# how to use slug and id both, as I'm getting comment_thread() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, django

is it possible to use slug and id together in one function?
I have this in my views.py

```
@login_required
def comment_thread(request, id, slug):
    hotCat = Category.objects.get_hotCat()
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
    post.save()      # and save it

    comment = Comment.objects.get(id=id)
    form = CommentForm()
    context = {
    "form": form,
    "comment": comment,
    "hotCat":hotCat,
    #"post":post
    }
    return render(request, "comments/comment_thread.html", context)
```

with this I get comment_thread() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
so I thought the problem is my urls.py which originally was

```
url(r'^comment/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'comment_thread', name='comment_thread'),
```

but even after I switched to

```
    url(r'^comment/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', 'comment_thread', name='comment_thread'),
```

it gave me page not found. 
so I realized, the problem is

```
<a href='{{ comment.get_absolute_url }}' target="_blank">
```

and I need to change

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('comment_thread', kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

But here's where I'm stuck.

this is my model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, blank=True, related_name="commented_post")
    text = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = CommentManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('comment_thread', kwargs={"id": self.id})


class Post(models.Model):

    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

I'm just lost how I can use slug for post in comment_thread view, so I can use post in my template.

Also seperate from this question, does any one know how to have target="_blank" effect;opening in a new tab while existing page remains for HttpResponseRedirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `slug` field to your model. Refer example below :

```
class Comment(models.ModelField):
   .... # all other fields
   slug = models.SlugField()

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if not self.id:
       self.slug = slugify(self.name)
     super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then your `get_absolute_url` becomes

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return reverse('comment_thread', kwargs={"id" : self.id, "slug" : self.slug})
```

The `save` function defined above basically sets the slug of the model the first time its saved (using its name as the url). This prevents the url of your comment from changing even if you edit it later.

Even for `Post` change the `slug` field to `models.SlugField()`

Comment: hello it gives me 404 error, now the url takes me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment/184/slug/ but when it was just http://127.0.0.1:8000/comment/184/ the page was found

Comment: I have     url(r'^comment/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', 'comment_thread', name='comment_thread'),
in my urls.py

Comment: and do u know how to have target="_blank" effect;opening in a new tab while existing page remains for HttpResponseRedirect?

Comment: Once you make the change and migrate, you will need to add slug's value to all your existing database Comments (either write a script/do it  manually). Restart your server and it should work. to get target="_blank" just use it normally. Eg : `<a href="{% url 'redirects' %}" target="_blank">` . Should work properly IMO.

Comment: Hey man I posted a question, would you please look at it?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956358/do-i-have-two-auth-profile-module-with-myprofile-objects-get-it-works-but-with