# Do I have two AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE? with MyProfile.objects.get it works but with post.moderator nothing is shown

Tags: python, django

In my settings.py I have `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.MyProfile'`

but in my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Maybe I should've used MyProfile there instead of User. Perhaps I'm having this problem:
In my views.py

```
        profile = post.moderator.__class__.objects.get(username=post.moderator.username)
```

and with that profile I have the following in my template

```
<a href="{% url 'userena_profile_detail' post.moderator.username %}"><img src="{{ profile.get_mugshot_url }}" /></span></a> </div>
```

This does not show anything. but if I were to do this in views.py

```
profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
```

I get an image of my profile. I should be getting the image of post.moderator but I get mine. any help please,what should I do, where did I mess up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you would do the query like that. The moderator *is* the user, so there doesn't seem to be any good reason to go back to the class and query by username; you already have the user.

Your query would not give you the UserProfile in any case. If you want that you just need to follow the relation from User to UserProfile:

```
profile = post.moderator.userprofile
```

assuming you have a one-to-one field from UserProfile to User.

Also note AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE has long been removed; and it wouldn't have done anything in this case anyway, as it was only invoked when you called `get_profile` and you weren't.

Comment: I did query set like that because for some reason profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id) shows the image while profile=post.moderator doesn't. The image still isn't shown. I'm using userena by the way, trying to display mugshot

Comment: I found the reason for this, it's because I have     moderator = models.ForeignKey(User), User should be MyProfile....is there a way to fix this without changing this line because I've already used User for long time already I don't want to alter anything else but for this

Comment: I tried that I get 'User' object has no attribute 'userprofile' because I need MyProfile to use userprofile I think...do all user objects have userprofile?I thought I had to use userena has profile which is MyProfile

Comment: by changing from     moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
to moderator = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile) it works...but I need to change everything I did for User to MyProfile

Comment: You still need to show the rest of your models, otherwise I can't help.

Comment: I figured it out thank you, I switched to MyProfile and changed everything I had to